# How to keep the value of "a parameter of a class" CONSTANT so that it can be accessed from other classes?

Tags: c++

***Request: I have solved my problem so, i request everyone to please stop down voting the question. I have written my Answer below my question.***

I have **three classes** i.e.

`class-A` ,

`class-B` ,

`class-C`.

- A parameter named `int value` is declared in `class A`
- I want to initialize it in `class B` i.e. `A.value = 0;`
- and finally i want to use that `value` in `class C`

Problem: How do i access the same value?

**Solution:** I HAVE ALREADY SOLVED THE PROBLEM. AND THIS IS MY SOLUTION

My three classes;

```
class A
{
    int value;    
}

class B
{
    void setValue();    
}

class C
{
    void useValue;    

}
```

Now, the methods of the above classes

```
void B:setValue()
{
    A object;
    object.value = 10;    
    useValue(object);
}

void C:useValue(A object)
{

    cout<<"Parameter: "<<object.value;
}
```

Comment: Those aren't the same `object`.

Comment: Time to read [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: ohhhhhhh i got your meaning but what should i do to use the same `object` for both the classes?

Comment: You should probably not create three separate classes if two of them have the exclusive purpose of accessing data stored in the third one.

Comment: yes they have to be seperate. This is just a template of my problem

Comment: Then please explain your real problem. And read a OO/C++ beginners book. You can´t have one object with many independent classes.

Comment: i have updated my question. Please have a look

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION 1:**
What you can do is to pass the object you need to work on as a parameter to the functions in class B and C.

Look at the following piece of code:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int parameter;
};

class B
{
    public:
    void setParameter(A &obj);
};

class C
{
    public:
    void accessParameter(A &obj);
};

//defining the functions

void B::setParameter(A &object)
{   
    object.parameter = 10;
}

void C::accessParameter(A &object)
{    
    std::cout<<"The value of parameter is: "<<object.parameter;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem. If not, post in the comments.

**NOTE**: You will need to make an object of A in main function and pass it to the methods of class B and C.

---

**SOLUTION 2:**
Another thing you can do is set up an inheritance chain:

C inherits B which inherits A.

So,

```
class A
{
    public:
    int parameter;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    void setParameter(){
        parameter = 10; 
    }
};

class C : public B
{
    public:

    C(){
        setParameter();
    }

    void accessParameter(){
        std :: cout << parameter;
    }

};
```

---

**SOLUTION 3**

Another solution would be making `parameter` a static field.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    static int parameter;
};

int A::parameter;

class B
{
    public:
    void setParameter();
};

class C
{
    public:
    void accessParameter();
};

//defining the functions

void B::setParameter()
{   
    A::parameter = 10;
}

void C::accessParameter()
{    
    std::cout<<"The value of parameter is: "<< A::parameter;
}

int main(){

    B objB;
    objB.setParameter();
    C objC;
    objC.accessParameter(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but in my case, they is no connection between them, i mean they are not connected through the same `main()`

Comment: Frankly, it would be better if you gave a proper problem statement including all the conditions. Please give the exact question that has been asked and not what you interpret the question as. I hope you understand.

Comment: I am not copying the question from somewhere or given to me by someone. I am facing this problem in my Project so, i have written the simplified version of my problem instead of posting the hi-fi code.

Comment: thanks but didn't i mention clearly this time that they are independent then how can i use inheritance?

Comment: In simpler words the problem is to set the parameter value in `class-B` which remain same for `class-2` as well by keeping my structure same.

Comment: why do i need void `(A &object)` as argument in `void B::setParameter(A &object)` in your solution-3

Comment: yes, i thought so. I tried your method but then i am getting an error that `undefined reference to A::parameter ` for the line `A::parameter = 10;`

Comment: @skm : Made some modifications. Code now works properly. If this helped please +1 and accept the answer. ;)

Comment: I checked in a seperate file, it is working but in my project where each class is defined in separate "header.h" files it is giving me error. I have not forgotten to use `#include "header.h"` . Anyways i am giving it +1

Comment: @skm: Headers are not for initialization. They are for providing interface declarations. [Taken from here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860895/way-to-initialize-static-members-in-the-header)

Comment: But when/where did i say that i am initializing in headers?

Comment: @skm : I think you need to research the problem a bit more. I am just a student with not much experience with headers. That was something I found that I thought might help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

`object` is local variable here. It is deleted when program lives setParameter() function

```
void B::setParameter()
{
    A object;
    object.parameter = 10;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i just forgot that fact but i have updated my question. I must access the value in from other class