# How to define a static member struct in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class that has a static member struct

```
class SharedMem
{
public:     

    struct memory { 
        char buff[100]; 
        int status, pid1, pid2; 
    }; 

    static struct memory* shmptr; 
}
```

I would like to define the static struct using 
`SharedMem::memory shmptr;`

But I'm getting errors `undefined reference to 'SharedMem::shmptr'`

How do I properly define the struct in C++?

And follow up question, how can I define this struct if my class is entirely in the header file, can I define it after the class declaration at the bottom of the header file?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to static variable c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284629/undefined-reference-to-static-variable-c)

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860895/how-to-initialize-static-members-in-the-header) answers your second question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
class SharedMem
{
public:     

    struct memory { 
        char buff[100]; 
        int status, pid1, pid2; 
    }; 

    static memory* shmptr; 
};
```

```cpp
// must add this in the cpp file!
SharedMem::memory* SharedMem::shmptr = nullptr;
```