# Singleton over microcontroller

Tags: c++, singleton

I am trying to use Singleton pattern in an embedded project, but I can't compile the project. The class, now, is very simple and I don't understand the problem.

The error is (48, in my code is the last line of instance function):

```
RadioWrapper.h:48: undefined reference to `RadioWrapper::mInstance'
```

Any ideas?

```cpp
#define RADIOWRAPPER_H_

class RadioWrapper
{
protected:
    RadioWrapper() {};
    ~RadioWrapper() { mInstance = NULL;}

public:

    static RadioWrapper* instance (void)
    {
        if (!mInstance)
        {
            mInstance = new RadioWrapper();
            return mInstance;
        }
        else
        {
            return mInstance;
        }
    }

    void setRx (void);

private:
    static RadioWrapper* mInstance;

};

#endif /* RADIOWRAPPER_H_ */
```

Comment: Works for me. Please provide a [mre] for the next to try your code. -- Which compiler do you use, how do you compile (command line)?

Comment: If you have a compiler in your environment, that does support c++11 or more modern, then search for "Meyers singleton", a safe and easy pattern.

Comment: @kaba I am using g++14 on microcontroller. I will search Meyers singleton. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static member of a class, like `static RadioWrapper* mInstance`,
has to be defined (what you have in the H file is a declaration only).

You need to add:

```
/*static*/ RadioWrapper::mInstance = nullptr;
```

(the `/*static*/` prefix is for documentation only).

This should be added in a CPP file, not H file (otherwise if the H file is included more than once, you'll have multiple definitions.)

If you are using C++ 17, you can use an `inline` variable that can be defined and initialized in the H file. See the 2nd answer here: [How to initialize static members in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860895/how-to-initialize-static-members-in-the-header)