# Boost DFS how to save visited vertices?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, depth-first-search

I'm looking at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189967/c-boost-graph-library-building-a-vector-of-vertices-visited-in-an-undirected), which doesn't work for me (but read under the === line to actually see the current problem).

I tried:

```
boost::undirected_dfs(G, vertex(0,G), boost::visitor(vis));
```

but I get

```
error C2780: 'void boost::undirected_dfs(const Graph &,const boost::bgl_named_params<P,T,R> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
error C2780: 'void boost::undirected_dfs(const Graph &,DFSVisitor,VertexColorMap,EdgeColorMap)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided
```

etc. I sort of get what the problem is (I need to pass it some named parameters, but I don't have any in my graph, I think. Also, I don't get what the deal with the color maps is, at all.

=============================================================================

My graph is defined:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, EdgeInfoProperty > Graph;
typedef Graph::edge_descriptor Edge;
typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
```

All I want is to do DFS, at least for now.

So I changed it to `boost::depth_first_search`, and it seems to work.

I have (note the lack of `const` for `void discover_vertex` vs. the solution linked above):

```
class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor {
public:
    void discover_vertex(Vertex v, const Graph& g)  { //note the lack of const
        if(boost::in_degree(v,g)!=0){ //only print the vertices in the connected component (I already did MCC and removed edges so all the extra vertices are isolated)
            std::cerr << v << std::endl;
            vv.push_back(v);
        }
        return;
    }
    std::vector<Vertex> GetVector() const  { return vv; }
private: 
    std::vector<Vertex> vv;
};
```

If I leave `const` there I get `error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer with [  _Ty=size_t  ]`.

Now, this works fine or at least it prints out the right visited vertices, in the right order:

```
MyVisitor vis;
boost::depth_first_search(G, boost::visitor(vis));
```

But when I do:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vctr = vis.GetVector();
std::cout<<vctr.size();
```

the size is zero, because my `vv` doesn't change...

So, how can I get the appropriate class behavior when the class is used as an argument to `boost::visitor`? (I'm not even sure this is the appropriate question). I need to be able to change `EdgeInfoProperty` based on which nodes were visited before (or rather based on which vertex is the parent of the current vertex in the DFS traversal, so this would probably just be a first step towards that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visitor is passed by value, so you need to share the vector it holds with the instance of MyVisitor copied into the function call.

Try this:

```
class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor {
public:
    MyVisitor(): vv(new std::vector<Vertex>()){}

    void discover_vertex(Vertex v, const Graph& g)  { //note the lack of const
        if(boost::in_degree(v,g)!=0){ //only print the vertices in the connected component (I already did MCC and removed edges so all the extra vertices are isolated)
            std::cerr << v << std::endl;
            vv->push_back(v);
        }
        return;
    }
    std::vector<Vertex>& GetVector() const  { return *vv; }
private: 
    boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<Vertex> > vv;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a global variable or a static data member to store the traversal results.

#### Global variable

[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ddc9a173efc63b3)

This approach is very versatile but also feels a bit quick-and-dirty. Note that you need to reset `g_vertices` before starting a new traversal. There are two benefits of using a global variable and a `Visitor` template with a `void operator()(...)` method.

1. You can use [`EventVisitor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/doc/EventVisitor.html) to toggle between pre-order and post-order traversal, and even extend it to other events.
2. I name the visitor `MyVisitor` instead of a more restrictive `MyDFSVisitor` because you can also apply it to other Boost Graph Library algorithms such as [`breadth_first_search()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html).

```cpp
// Pre-order and post-order DFS traversal on an undirected graph with a global
// variable
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using MyGraph = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type>>;
using MyVertex = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor;

namespace {
// Global variable to store traversal results
std::vector<MyVertex> g_vertices;
} // namespace

template <typename Event> struct MyVisitor : public boost::null_visitor {
  // Capture event type to allow both pre-order and post-order traversal
  using event_filter = Event;

  template <typename Vertex, typename Graph>
  void operator()(Vertex v, const Graph &g) {
    g_vertices.push_back(v);
  }
};

int main() {
  MyGraph g{};
  boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
  boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 3, g);

  auto root = boost::vertex(0, g);
  auto color_map = boost::get(boost::vertex_color, g);

  {
    // Pre-order [0, 1, 2, 3]
    std::cout << "pre-order traversal:\n";
    auto vis = boost::make_dfs_visitor(MyVisitor<boost::on_discover_vertex>());
    boost::depth_first_search(g, vis, color_map, root);
    for (auto v : g_vertices) {
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    g_vertices.clear();
  }
  {
    // Post-order [2, 3, 1, 0]
    std::cout << "post-order traversal:\n";
    auto vis = boost::make_dfs_visitor(MyVisitor<boost::on_finish_vertex>());
    boost::depth_first_search(g, vis, color_map, root);
    for (auto v : g_vertices) {
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    g_vertices.clear();
  }
}
```

#### Static data member

Here, I write `MyDFSVisitor` as a template struct to make it more transferrable to other use cases.

[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe8f64d871f3b9c9)

```cpp
// Pre-order and post-order DFS traversal on an undirected graph with a static
// data member
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using MyGraph = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type>>;

using MyVertex = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor;

template <typename Vertex>
struct MyDFSVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor {
  inline static std::vector<Vertex> m_preorder_vertices;
  inline static std::vector<Vertex> m_postorder_vertices;

  // pre-order traversal
  template <typename Graph> void discover_vertex(Vertex v, const Graph &g) {
    m_preorder_vertices.push_back(v);
  }

  // post-order traversal
  template <typename Graph> void finish_vertex(Vertex v, const Graph &g) {
    m_postorder_vertices.push_back(v);
  }
};

int main() {
  MyGraph g{};
  boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
  boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 3, g);

  auto root = boost::vertex(0, g);
  auto color_map = boost::get(boost::vertex_color, g);

  MyDFSVisitor<MyVertex> vis;
  boost::depth_first_search(g, vis, color_map, root);
  std::cout << "Pre-order traversal : \n"; // 0 1 2 3
  for (auto v : vis.m_preorder_vertices) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "Post-order traversal : \n"; // 2 3 1 0
  for (auto v : vis.m_postorder_vertices) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
  }
}
```