# Boost Graph Library - Depth First Search only through connected vertices

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to run a DFS through my graph which has multiple disjoint graphs. I'd like to specify the start vertex and have the DFS only traverse through *that* tree, keeping the vertex ID visited in a vector. To do this, I would need the depth_first_visit function http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_visit.html

The function requires me to initialize a color map and I am clueless in doing it because I also have a custom vertex and a custom edge. The best example I got was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126/how-to-create-a-c-boost-undirected-graph-and-traverse-it-in-depth-first-search) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166500/boost-dfs-how-to-save-visited-vertices) post which talks about depth first search not depth first visit. If I were to replace the vertex with the structure I used then it would be the code below.

So to reiterate, I'm clueless as to how I should initialize a color map and set the start vertex for a custom vertex type. I hope someone can give me a simple example. Been googling the past several hours but couldn't find an example.

```
// Boost DFS example on an undirected graph.
// Create a sample graph, traverse its nodes
// in DFS order and print out their values.

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//======================================================================================================
//information representing each vertex
struct Vertex {

public:

    //id
    int id = 0;
    int parent_id = -1;
    int l_child = -1, r_child = -1;

    Vertex(int id = -1) : id(id) {}
};

//======================================================================================================
//information representing each weight
//it carries the boundary length and also the distance
struct Edge {

    //distance
    float boundary_length = 0;
    float weight = 1;
    //float L, a, b = 1;

    Edge(float boundary_length = 1) : boundary_length(boundary_length) {}
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;

class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor
{
public:

    MyVisitor() : vv(new std::vector<int>()) {}

    void discover_vertex(int v, const Graph& g) const
    {
        vv->push_back(g[v].id);
        return;
    }

    std::vector<int>& GetVector() const { return *vv; }

    private:
    boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > vv;
};

int main()
{

  Graph g;
  boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
  boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 3, g);

  boost::add_edge(5, 6, g);
  boost::add_edge(5, 8, g);

  MyVisitor vis;
  boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(vis));

  std::vector<int> vctr = vis.GetVector();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest approach is to create a vector to contain a color for each vertex.

Simplest way to achieve *that* is:

```
auto indexmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);
auto colormap = boost::make_vector_property_map<boost::default_color_type>(indexmap);
```

Which you then pass like

```
boost::depth_first_search(g, vis, colormap);
```

That's equivalent to using the named parameter idiom like:

```
boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(vis) .color_map(colormap));
```

To also supply a start vertex, simply use that overload:

```
boost::depth_first_search(g, vis, colormap, 1);
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59f50d463bf08002)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//======================================================================================================
// information representing each vertex
struct Vertex {

    int id = 0;
    int parent_id = -1;
    int l_child = -1, r_child = -1;

    Vertex(int id = -1) : id(id) {}
};

//======================================================================================================
// information representing each weight
// it carries the boundary length and also the distance
struct Edge {

    // distance
    float boundary_length = 0;
    float weight = 1;
    // float L, a, b = 1;

    Edge(float boundary_length = 1) : boundary_length(boundary_length) {}
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;

class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor {
  public:
    MyVisitor() : vv(new std::vector<int>()) {}

    void discover_vertex(int v, const Graph &g) const {
        vv->push_back(g[v].id);
        return;
    }

    std::vector<int> &GetVector() const { return *vv; }

  private:
    boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > vv;
};

int main() {

    Graph g;
    boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
    boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
    boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
    boost::add_edge(1, 3, g);

    boost::add_edge(5, 6, g);
    boost::add_edge(5, 8, g);

    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g)))
        g[v] = Vertex(v);

    auto indexmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    auto colormap = boost::make_vector_property_map<boost::default_color_type>(indexmap);

    MyVisitor vis;
    boost::depth_first_search(g, vis, colormap, 1);

    std::vector<int> vctr = vis.GetVector();

    for(auto id : vctr)
        std::cout << id << " ";
}
```

Prints

```
1 0 2 3 4 5 6 8 7
```

Comment: and to visit only vertices that are connected i can make use of the depth_first_visit function. thank you again !